# Como eu faço para citar uma variavel do codigo php no java script

Tags: php, javascript

php

```
    <td style="text-align:center"><div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup";>
```

js

```
    function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

gostaria de algo do tipo

```
    <td style="text-align:center"><div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup<?php echo $variavel ?>";>
```

```
    function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup + $variavel");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Comment: `<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $variavel; ?>)">Click me!` e `function myFuncion(variavel){var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup" + variavel); ...}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Respondendo unicamente a sua pergunta:

Imagine que você possui uma variável no php, por exemplo `$variavel = 'valor';` e deseja que esta variável, exista no javascript e possua o mesmo valor.

Existem duas formas de fazer isto, onde a única diferença é a sintaxe.

1ª Forma:

```
<?php 
$variavel = 'valor';
echo '<script>var variavel = ' . $variavel . '</script>';
?>
```

2ª Forma: (eu particularmente prefiro):

```
<?php $variavel = 'valor'; //variável existe no ambiente php. ?>
<script>
var variavel = <?= $var ?>
</script>
```